# Xcode playground - Swift 4 not receiving the JSON data

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-playground

Hi I am working in Xcode playground and trying to use API http-get request using URLSession with the dummy data from jsonplaceholder website.

See code below. The code doesn't return an error but I was expecting data in "usableData" and print it. And the data is :

> { URL: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 } { Status Code: 200, Headers {\n    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" =     (\n        true\n    );\n    "CF-Cache-Status" =     (\n        HIT\n    );\n    "CF-RAY" =     (\n        "445f3d1003761d3e-MEL"\n    );\n    "Cache-Control" =     (\n        "public, max-age=14400"\n    );\n    Connection =     (\n        "keep-alive"\n    );\n    "Content-Encoding" =     (\n        gzip\n    );\n    "Content-Type" =     (\n        "application/json; charset=utf-8"\n    );\n    Date =     (\n        "Mon, 06 Aug 2018 05:52:38 GMT"\n    );\n    Etag =     (\n        "W/\"1fd-+2Y3G3w049iSZtw5t1mzSnunngE\""\n    );\n    Expires =     (\n        "Mon, 06 Aug 2018 09:52:38 GMT"\n    );\n    Pragma =     (\n        "no-cache"\n    );\n    Server =     (\n        cloudflare\n    );\n    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (\n        Identity\n    );\n    Vary =     (\n        "Origin, Accept-Encoding"\n    );\n    Via =     (\n        "1.1 ve…"

I was expecting some JSON formated data along the lines of :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
        "street": "Kulas Light",
        "suite": "Apt. 556",
        "city": "Gwenborough",
        "zipcode": "92998-3874",
        "geo": {
            "lat": "-37.3159",
            "lng": "81.1496"
        }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
        "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
        "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
        "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
}
```

At this phase I am only interested in getting the data and not parsing it yet.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is welcome. thank you.

---- START CODE ---------------

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let urlString = URL(string:"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")

if let url = urlString {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {              
            print()
        } else {
            if let usableData = data {
                print(usableData) //JSONSerialization
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The code should work and print `"509 bytes"`. And optional binding `if let usableData` is redundant. If there is no error `data` can be safely unwrapped.

Comment: correct and I got the 509 bytes. I will try to convert to readable JSON.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to use Foundation class, NSJSONSerialization for converting json data which you get from your api into an object. So you can use line below:

```
let usableData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
print(usableData)
```

Comment: The question is about Swift 4, where we have `Codable` and `JSONDecoder`. `NSJSONSerialization` should be avoided.

Comment: ok, can you give me an example of this in my code? I thought coddle was more to do with parsing once the data is obtained. I am not there yet. @Gereon please give me an example using my code. thx

Comment: Exactly, `Codable` is for parsing JSON data into actual Swift objects. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @RvE How could you accept this answer? It doesn't even compile in Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. If you want to see the JSON data printed as a String, you need to convert the bytes from `data` to a String:

```
if let usableData = data {
    let str = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("\(String(describing: str))") // just for debug output
}
```

Note that this is not necessary for parsing, you'd do something along the lines of

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, username, email: String
    let address: Address
    let phone, website: String
    let company: Company
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let street, suite, city, zipcode: String
    let geo: Geo
}

struct Geo: Codable {
    let lat, lng: String
}

struct Company: Codable {
    let name, catchPhrase, bs: String
}

if let usableData = data {
    try {
       let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
    } catch {
       print("\(error)"
    }
}
```

for that

Comment: Please don't suggest tautologic syntax like `print("\(String(describing: str))")`. A string from JSON data can never be `nil`. `print(str!)` is sufficient.

Comment: Well, nothing in the code (nor on the server, as far as I can tell) really ensures there's JSON involved. As such, we don't know anything about what bytes we have in `data`, and therefore the conversion to String may in fact fail, and that's why I'm reluctant to recommend force unwrapping to a beginner.

Comment: Paste `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1` into a browser and have a look. It **is** json. But I was more concerned about printing a **string** with string interpolation which was created from a **string** with the `describing` initializer. Besides the OP wrote *At this phase I am only interested in getting the data and not parsing it yet*

Comment: And Vadian is correct. This gives the result..             if let usableData = data {
            let str = String(bytes: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            print("\(str!))") // just for debug output

Comment: Thx all for your help and my trial and erring in my xcode playground. Now the new evolution will be parsing.